# Small caps only for the reference list

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to make a last (?) modification to my `biblatex` formatting by putting the authors name in small caps, but just in the reference list.

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

puts the authors name in small caps both in the reference list and in the citation.

What would you recommend?

Edit:

I am adding an example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend = biber, natbib, maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames=99, minnames=1, giveninits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{key,
    address = {Vienna},
    edition = {Österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften},
    title = {Cremation burials in {Greece} from the {Late} {Bronze} {Age} to the {Early} {Iron} {Age}: continuity or change?},
    booktitle = {Brandbestattungen von der mittleren {Donau} bis zur Ägäis zwischen 1300 und 750 v. {Chr}.},
    author = {Ruppenstein, Florian},
    editor = {Lochner, M. and Ruppenstein, Florian},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {185--196},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{: }
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{ }%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{author}{\mkbibacro{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{author}{\sc #1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{, in }
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}%
}



\begin{document}

This is the good reference \citep{key}.

\printbibliography

\noindent Expected output:

\textsc{Ruppenstein}, F. 2013. Cremation burials in Greece from the Late Bronze Age to the Early Iron Age: continuity or change?, in M. Lochner \& F. Ruppenstein (ed.) \emph{Brandbestattungen von der mittleren Donau bis zur Ägäis zwischen 1300 und 750 v. Chr.}: 185--196. Vienna: Österreichischen Akademie der Wissenschaften.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want all (family) names in small caps in the bibliography or only those of the author?

Comment: Note that it is not guaranteed that all (usual) approaches work with all styles, so if you want to make sure you get an answer that is tested against your setup, you need to tell us more about how you have set up citations and the bibliography. This is best done in a so-called minimal working example: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: Hi @moewe, thank you again. Only the authors (not editors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most standard styles (all except the `numeric`- and `alphabetic`-based styles) the following should work

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,westfahl:space}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Westfahl 2000)" no small caps. Small caps in bibliography]

In `numeric`- and `alphabetic`-based styles standard styles you might need the three additional lines

```
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}
```